# $elemMatch differences in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm seeing some differences between 2.0.7 and 2.2.0 when it comes to the $elemMatch operation.

**In 2.2.0, I do get results back with this query:**

```
db.testColl.find( { "metadata" : {$elemMatch : {$gt : {age:23}, $lt : {age:99}} }});
```

**In 2.0.7, I don't get any results back.**

For testing purposes, I have only one document in my testColl collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fb2974cbedb4a626109b002"),
    "metadata" : [
        {
            "age" : 59
        },
        {
            "gender" : "FEMALE"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know why this works in 2.2.0, but not 2.0.7?

According to this:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch

elemMatch is supported for v1.4+

Thanks,
Galen

Comment: Just tried this on my 2.2.1 system and the above query **did** return the document.

Comment: JohnnyHK:  I'm sorry I had stated my question incorrectly.  I have updated it now.  I had the versions backwards -- 2.0.7 is the version that DOESN'T return results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way that works in both versions, you don't need to use `$elemMatch` here because you're only comparing against a single field so you can use a simpler query.  Try this instead:

```js
db.testColl.find({ 'metadata.age': { $gt: 23, $lt: 99 }});
```

Comment: @JonnyHK:  This does work, however it doesn't fully leverage the index (I need to create one on 'metadata').  I have talked to 10gen, and got a solution (basically upgrading to 2.2.1 is my best option).  I'm giving you the point on this one though :)  Thanks!